# C# Windows Forms Design-time Form constructor not called?

Tags: forms, constructor, design-time

Is the constructor of a form not called upon opening the form in design view? Why not? Can I somehow force it to be called?
I tested it by showing a MessageBox in the constructor, and only the MessageBox from the constructor of the form's base type (another form) is shown...

Comment: If you are creating an instance of the form, it should be called. What do you mean by opening the form in design view?

Answer (score 2):

This behavior is by design. The form designer in Visual Studio cannot instantiate the class *being designed* — instead, it instatiates its immediate parent. There is no way to change this behavior. If you need some logic to be executed during design time, you have to create a separate ancestor encapsulating that logic and inherit from it.

That's also the reason why in order to be able to use the designer you cannot inherit a form from an abstract or generic class.

Comment: Ok, maybe you can help me with this then: the base form does smth depending on a property which I want the user to be able to set in the derived form. But when the user sets properties in the designer, its added in th InitialComponents() method, which is called from the constructor. So in the base form, the changes to the property are not visible (in the design time)... how can I let the base form know if the property is changed (in the design time)?

Comment: @nogola You can't. The property declared in the form *being designed* does not exist in the actual instance used by the designer.

Comment: But how does the designer then know for example the position of a control i just added to the form? As far as I know, this information is in the InitialComponents() method. And thats also the place where my property is modified...