# ConnectionString error after form inheritance?

Tags: c#, inheritance, connection-string, app-config

I am building a C# application, and a problem occurred, I have no idea how to fix it though.

I have a couple of forms, and now I want to add a form which is inherited by another. When I want to view the [Design] screen of the new form, it gives me the following error:

> Object reference not set to an instance of an object.

Now I found out that the problem was the connection string, which is located in the `app.config` file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<configuration>
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="ConnString" connectionString="Data Source=.\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PVB;Integrated Security=True" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
</configuration>
```

This is my code for the connectionString in C#:

```
string connectionString = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["ConnString"].ConnectionString;
```

If I use the string like the one above, I get the `Object Reference blabla` error. Suprisingly, when I use the following code, the form just works perfectly fine:

```
string connectionString = "Data Source=.\\SQLEXPRESS;Initial Catalog=PVB;Integrated Security=True";
```

Does anyone have a clue how I can fix this problem? Yes, I've added the `System.Configuration` reference to the solution, so that's not the problem, I guess..

Comment: Do you get any error when running the code?  Or only in design mode? FYI the "Object Reference blabla" error is a NullReferenceException.

Comment: @Fermin I only get it in design mode, when I run it it works perfectly fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please review the following URL which might resolve your issue. It seems that the problem here is simulair:

[access app.config from inherited form](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12602326/accessing-connection-string-from-base-form-causes-designer-error)

Comment: I guess that works, but I still wonder why I can't use the ConnectionString from the app.config, do you have an explanation for that?

Comment: Answer in link from IamKrillin: What is actually happening here is that the constructor is not being called when you put that stuff in your parent class. However when you do a sub class relationship it has to be called. That is visual studio constructs the parent class not the child class you are working with http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4546311/c-sharp-windows-forms-design-time-form-constructor-not-called